# Simple way to add columns from multiple files

Tags: bash, awk, paste

If I have multiple files like this:

filename1.txt

```
# 0.2
1.0 0.0
1.5 1.0
2.0 0.8
2.5 1.1
```

filename2.txt

```
# 0.5
1.0 0.1
1.5 0.6
2.0 1.3
2.5 0.4
```

where all of their first columns are the same. I simply want an output like:

```
# 0.7
1.0 0.1
1.5 1.6
2.0 2.1
2.5 1.5
```

I know that

```
paste filename1.txt filename2.txt | awk '{print $1, $2+$4}'
```

works but it is unfeasible when there are over 20 files. I have also tried using

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2;next}{print $1,$2+a[FNR]}' filename1.txt filename2.txt
```

but it only works with 2 files then seems to ignore the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk '{a[FNR]=$1; s[FNR]+=$2} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print a[i], s[i]}' file1 file2
# 0.7
1.0 0.1
1.5 1.6
2.0 2.1
2.5 1.5
```

`FNR` starts from 1 for each file so you can pass all of your input files to this awk command.

Comment: Well, you were a few seconds faster. :P

Comment: Thanks, yes we both thought about exact same solution :)

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work. Another quick question: what if I have 10 files and want to add files 1 through 8 but not include file9 or file10? Is there a simple addition to this line or am I better off using a for loop?

Comment: `awk 'FILENAME ~ /filename9|filename10/ {next} {a[FNR]=$1; s[FNR]+=$2} END{for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++) print a[i], s[i]}' filename*`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you think the paste/awk solution is unfeasible. Here is one way you could do it, assuming each file only has 2 columns:

```
paste * | awk '{ s=$2; for(i=4; i<=NF; i+=2) s+=$i; print $1, s }'
```

Output:

```
1.0 0.1
1.5 1.6
2.0 2.1
2.5 1.5
```

Comment: you are right, this did work but for some reason it doesn't seem to work with the `FILENAME ~ /filename9|filename10/ {next} ` addition. Perhaps I missed something.